# How to block traffic from specific namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have multiple namespaces in my k8 cluster. All I want is that pods in development namespace can communicate with all other pods in other namespaces but should not be able to communicate with resources in production namespace.

I was not able to find a document for this scenario. There is a deny all policy like this

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
```

but it applies at pod level in the same namespace.  How can I modify the same to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring from the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource)

1. Label all namespaces in development environment with `environment=dev`
2. Label all namespaces in production environment with `environment=prod`

Then you can have network policy as below

1. Default deny policy as you have already
2. Have a policy to whitelist traffic to pods from namespaces with label `environment=prod`

As below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          environment: "prod"
```

Comment: I have seen something nameSelector can that be used in this scenario. Can not find any example though.

Comment: I have seen something nameSelector can that be used in this scenario. Can not find any example though.

Comment: so i guess policies are kind of allow only and what's not allowed is denied. In case I have 3 more namespaces from which I want to allow access, I need to add them also with name selector.

Comment: By default, pods are non-isolated; they accept traffic from any source